# How to take away extra bracket with \chemfig?

Tags: brackets, chemfig, parentheses

I just started using `chemfig` and I need the formula for a polymer. Everything is perfect except the fact that I **have an extra bracket**, as you can see from the picture.

[image]

My code is the following (the first part is just copied from the documentation for the `chemfig` package):

```
\newcommand\setpolymerdelim[2]

{\def\delimleft{#1}\def\delimright{#2}}\def\makebraces[#1,#2]#3#4#5{%
\edef\delimhalfdim{\the\dimexpr(#1+#2)/2}%
\edef\delimvshift{\the\dimexpr(#1-#2)/2}%
\chemmove{% 
    \node[at=(#4),yshift=(\delimvshift)]
    {$\left\delimleft\vrule height\delimhalfdim depth\delimhalfdim 
width0pt\right.$};%
    \node[at=(#5),yshift=(\delimvshift)]
    {$\left.\vrule height\delimhalfdim depth\delimhalfdim width0pt\right\delimright_{\rlap{$\scriptstyle#3$}}
    \left\delimleft\vrule height\delimhalfdim depth\delimhalfdim width0pt\right.$};}}
\setpolymerdelim[]


    \chemfig{[:18]-[@{open,.5}] *5((-)- S - (-[@{close,.5}] )= (-#(,6pt)(CH_2{(}CH_2{)}_4 CH_3)) - =)}
    \makebraces[45pt,10pt]{n}{open}{close}
```

How do I take away that extra bracket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code fragment, which is part of the last row of the macro definition to create the braces, is redundant:

```
\left\delimleft\vrule height\delimhalfdim depth\delimhalfdim width0pt\right.
```

Deleting it solves your problem.

Also, check that you are using the current version of the `ChemFig` Manual. This erronous line is not in version 1.2d of the Manual from December 2015. Maybe it's just a copy / paste error?

Here is the MWE, followed by the drawing of the polymer.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,crop=true]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\newcommand\setpolymerdelim[2]{\def\delimleft{#1}\def\delimright{#2}}
\def\makebraces[#1,#2]#3#4#5{%
    \edef\delimhalfdim{\the\dimexpr(#1+#2)/2}%
    \edef\delimvshift{\the\dimexpr(#1-#2)/2}%
    \chemmove{%
        \node[at=(#4),yshift=(\delimvshift)]
        {$\left\delimleft\vrule height\delimhalfdim depth\delimhalfdim
            width0pt\right.$};%
        \node[at=(#5),yshift=(\delimvshift)]
        {$\left.\vrule height\delimhalfdim depth\delimhalfdim
            width0pt\right\delimright_{\rlap{$\scriptstyle#3$}}$};}}
\setpolymerdelim[]

\begin{document}

    \chemfig{[:18]-[@{open,.5}] *5((-)- S - (-[@{close,.5}] )= (-#(,6pt)(CH_2{(}CH_2{)}_4 CH_3)) - =)}
    \makebraces[45pt,10pt]{n}{open}{close}

\end{document}
```

[image: polymer]